# Rails - Create new object with ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I have Competency and CompetencyType models. In the form for new Competency I would like to add a separate field Add new competency type which will create new CompetencyType.

```
= label_tag :title, t('competency.add_type'), class: 'control-label'
= text_field :title, nil, class: 'span12'
= submit_tag "Add", id: 'competency_type'
```

How can I make Ajax request to create new CompetencyType?

Comment: Firstly, did you try it already todo something before asking a question? Please, put you attempts here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 solution
 Add to form remote: true

2)

```
$(window).ready(function(){
 $("form").submit(function(e){
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: path,
   data: { 'title': $('title') }
  })
  .done(function( msg ) {
   alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
 });
});
```